# React JS Insert object into Firebase database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an object set initial data by useState like this

```
const Price = () => {
  const [price, setPrice] = useState({
    vehicleType: "",
    price: 0,
  });
```

And I insert into firestore

```
const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "VehiclePrices"), { price });
```

I expect my data would be

{vehicleType: '',price:0}

but It ends up like this

price: {{vehicleType: '',price:0}}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFkkz.png)

Any advice to make it insert like I need. Thanks in advance anyone.

Comment: Did A.Aydın's answer solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, He did solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write without the brackets.

```
const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "VehiclePrices"), price);
```

Comment: Oh man, how can I made this mistake. Thank you so much